# How can I get ``Widget`` position in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want get `Widget` position in flutter, but not using **`key`** of `Widget`.

Comment: you cannot do that - you need `GlobalKey`

Answer (score 0):

use [rect_getter](https://pub.dev/packages/rect_getter), a widget provide a simple way to get child's rectangle information after rendered.

Comment: I have `` Widget myButton`` how can I get position?

Comment: @AshKhachatryan so whats wrong with `GlobalKey`? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't want ``GlobalKey``